# PHP redundant typehinting on default null and ?type

Tags: php, null, type-hinting

```
public function foo(?myObject $object = null)
    // Do something
```

This seems to be redundant: Using typehint-"?" and set the default value to null? May I expect different results on different ways of executing this method?

Comment: They're doing slightly different things, although there is some overlap. `?myObject` means that it's *possible* to pass null, but you would still explicitly have to pass it. `= null` provides a default, so you can call the function without providing any argument at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the php 7 documentation, when you have it

```
public function foo (?myObject $object)
{
}
```

you have to override the null parameter when the function is called - otherwise there will be an error.

```
$this->foo(null); // it is ok
$this->foo(); // You have error
```

in php 5.x, the entry is correct

```
public function foo ($object = null)
{
}
```

then you can call the function without having to explicitly pass the null paramater

```
$this->foo();
```

If you do not want to pass null to php7 functions, you can use the connections php5 and php7 - for example

```
public function foo (?myObject $object = null)
{
}
```

then you can use the method call without having to pass a parameter

```
$this->foo();
```

**I think that thes (last) solution are impractical and I recommend choosing one of the solutions with php5.x or php7 (no mixing their).**

Answer (score 0):

Another way to pass a null value.

```
function foo(?Type $t) {
    }


$this->foo(new Type()); // ok
$this->foo(null); // ok
$this->foo(); // error
```